# What is mathematical definition of Binary tree>?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I need to know the academic definition of binary tree in graph theory, I do not need the computer science definition.

the common algebraic explanation of the "binary tree" which uses notions of father and sons (or parents and children).

Comment: How about: A binary tree is a rooted tree where all nodes have degree $\le 3$ and the root has degree $\le 2$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have write this definition of binary tree but teacher says it is more computer science definition, give me the mathematic one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291651/i-have-write-this-definition-of-binary-tree-but-teacher-says-it-is-more-computer)