# I have write this definition of binary tree but teacher says it is more computer science definition, give me the mathematic one

Tags: graph-theory, trees

[image: nitio]

So can you please tell me what is the academic mathematical definition of a binary tree? ( I even omitted the data element part and he didn't accept)
the text is:

" A binary tree is made of nodes, where each node contains a "left" reference, a "right"
reference, and a data element. The topmost node in the tree is called the root.
Every node (excluding a root) in a tree is connected by a directed edge from exactly one other
node. This node is called a parent. On the other hand, each node can be connected to
maximum two nodes, called children."

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Please type in your post what's written in the image. Always prefer text over attached images. Also, what do those red squares mean?

Comment: @evaristegd thank you for your comment sorry I am new and I edited the question put the text, those red square are nothing just his software problem with commenting

Comment: reference${}{}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown this link https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Trees/trees.html

Comment: No, what is a "reference"?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown it means "child" here, the thing is I even changed it to "child" but still he said it is not the mathematical definition he said "I am sorry to repeat my last commentary:
"The sentence mix altogether the algebraic notion (of a binary tree) with its use in computer science. Unfortunately, it cannot be clear to a reader not acknowledged with the use." 

I recommend to stay at the common algebraic explanation of the "binary tree" which uses notions of father and sons (or parents and children)."

Comment: The teacher sounds like a jerk. Are you in a class, or are they advising some kind of thesis you're writing? Are you in a position to ask then to clarify face to face?

Comment: @HenningMakholm it is my report for graph theory course, I just want to say is this any good scientific source, so Instead of fighting on it which you know you can not do with professors, I refer to that paper so he couldn't say anything?

Comment: You can read the Wikipedia article [Binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) for many important details and variations or distinctions.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your teacher's issue is not with the *substance* of your definition but with the *phrasing* you give it when you say that the nodes "contain" their children (or references to them).

Mathematicians would more often say that the tree simply has an **abstract set** of nodes, where the definition of "tree" doesn't care what each node looks like in details. Things like which nodes are children of which would usually be specified as something *external to* the nodes themselves -- say, in a separate set of edges, or partial functions $l$ or $r$ from nodes to other nodes, with particular properties. Similarly for other data you imagine the nodes to come with (which mathematicians would tend to call "labels").

When you define a *particular concrete tree* you would of course often let the nodes be objects where you encode things that the $l$ and $r$ functions pick out of them. But this would be an implementation detail for that particular tree which cannot be seen when you just say "Let $T$ be a tree".

You'd also need to say something like no node is both a left child and a right child, and every node is reachable from the root in finitely many steps.

Comment: Thank you dear Henning for your answer, I know it is too much to ask, since you are familiar with the subject can you kindly look at my other question relating to graph theory here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291641/i-can-not-find-my-mistake-in-ahu-algorithm-to-detect-if-two-trees-are-isomorphic

Comment: @SinaM Related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13083/how-to-get-a-question-answered